# Catalog_product_attribute list empty in Python-Magento API?

Tags: magento-enterprise, xmlrpc

Using [this](https://github.com/bernieke/python-magento) for fetching data from My Magento website. The catalog product API is working fine. It returns all the products. But when I try to fetch attribute using the following command it returns an empty list.

```
>>> magento = MagentoAPI("magentohost,com","80","**","**","/api/xmlrpc")
>>> products = magento.catalog_product.list()
>>> len(products)
3345
>>> attrs = magento.catalog_product_attribute.list()
>>> attrs
[]
```

I have lot of products attributes in my catalog. Why does it return empty then?

P.S: Is the JSON Magento API better than XML API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Python xmlrpc to manage my magento store this two days,
Very good but there are little document about python+xmlrpc.
I do not use MagentoAPI or Other third-party lib, I am worry that the library do not update.

```
import timeit
import xmlrpclib
import datetime

from pyexcel_ods import get_data
import json

client = None
session = None
user = 'username'
password = 'password'

def setup():
    global client, session
    # your domain here
    client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://www.magentohost.com.hk/index.php/api/xmlrpc?type=xmlrpc")
    # your credentials here
    session = client.login('username', 'password')

setup()


attribute_sets = client.call(session, 'catalog_product_attribute_set.list')
print attribute_sets

print "\n\n"

# show list all attribute of frist one set 
attributes = client.call(session, 'catalog_product_attribute.list',[attribute_sets[0]['set_id']])
print attributes
```

This is my frist time to answer stackexchange question.